# How to combine default query string params and request-specific params using Guzzle?

Tags: guzzle

When I run the following code (using the latest Guzzle, v6), the URL that gets requested is `http://example.com/foobar?foo=bar` dropping the `boo=far` from the request.

```
$guzzle_http_client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://example.com/',
    'query' => [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ],
]);

$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'foobar?boo=far');
$response = $guzzle_http_client->send($request);
```

When I run the following code, passing `boo=far` instead as part of the `Client::send()` method, the URL that gets requested is `http://example.com/foobar?boo=far`

```
$guzzle_http_client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://example.com/',
    'query' => [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ],
]);

$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'foobar');
$response = $guzzle_http_client->send($request, ['query' => ['boo' => 'far']]);
```

Of course, the URL that I want to be requested is:

```
http://example.com/foobar?foo=bar&bar=foo
```

How do I make Guzzle combine default client query string parameters with request-specific parameters?

Comment: This is a real pain! I created PSR7\Uri object with the static method `withQueryValue` and pass it to the constructor. But it didnt work either!

Answer (score 11):

You can try to get default 'query' options using 'getConfig' method and then merge them with new  'query' options, here an example:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://example.com/',
    'query'   => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

And then you can easy send a GET request:

```
$client->get('foobar', [
    'query' =>  array_merge(
        $client->getConfig('query'),
        ['bar' => 'foo']
     )
]);
```

Additional info you can find here [Request Options](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#request-options)